# Not able to use VNC on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, networking, vnc

My Raspberry Pi once upon a time was able to VNC perfectly but then it just stopped. Tightvnc Server works but when i do `netstat | grep 5901` the connection doesn't show up. I try using `tightvncviewer 192.168.0.200` but nothing shows up neither. However I am able to use the ssh service on my Raspberry Pi. I am using Remmina Remote Desktop Client to try to access it on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that VNC is running? By default VNC does not normally run automatically. So you may have been setting it up and started to run it. Then when your RPi was restarted, VNC was not automatically restarted.

Here is how to configure VNC to [run on startup](http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server).

Create a file in /etc/init.d with a suitable name such as vncboot with the following content.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vncboot
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start VNC Server at boot time
# Description: Start VNC Server at boot time.
### END INIT INFO

#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/vncboot

USER=root
HOME=/root

export USER HOME

case "$1" in
 start)
   echo "Starting VNC Server"
   #Insert your favoured settings for a VNC session
   /usr/bin/vncserver :0 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 16 -pixelformat rgb565
   ;;

 stop)
   echo "Stopping VNC Server"
   /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :0
   ;;

 *)
   echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vncboot {start|stop}"
   exit 1
   ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Modify the file permissions so it can be executed

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/vncboot
```

Enable dependency based boot sequencing

```
update-rc.d /etc/init.d/vncboot defaults
```

If enabling dependency based boot sequencing was successful, it says

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

But if it says

```
update-rc.d: error: unable to read /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/vncboot
```

then try the following command

```
update-rc.d vncboot defaults
```

Reboot your Raspberry PI and you should find a vncserver already started.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your firewall right and unblock port 5901.